# Zipping up Node App and having dependencies work out of box

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs

I created a Node app that relies on a dependency (Jest) that is just for running tests.

I want to zip this app up and run it and its tests on another machine that has node installed.

My package.json includes

"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },

and jest is included in the app's npm_modules folder.

The tests work perfectly on the machine that the app was developed on. However, upon extracting the zip and running on another computer, I get an error that jest is not found.

I then reinstalled jest without '--save-dev' and installed it for production use, thinking this would resolve the error, but it did not.

I thought the point of having npm_modules and using 'npm install' was so that the app's dependencies can all be localized and portable i.e. not having host machine have to install modules separately.

Is there any way to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the PATH. On the first machine the path includes a `node_modules/.bin` directory which doesn't appear on the second.

Comment: I would bet that the original machine is using a global version of jest.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/365uz is a log file from node. I find it interesting that Line 8 seems to be showing various PATH variables for node. The second one is in fact my 'app/node_modules/.bin' folder, so I find it strange that this does not work (and jest is in fact in that folder) In addition, I even tried adding 'app/node_modules/bin/jest' to my Windows PATH list and it still didn't work. I think this is a quirky windows thing. But it seems weird that this is an issue. Surely many people expect to be able to run an app without installing global dependencies on windows?

Answer (score 1):

According to `"scripts": { "test": "jest" },` you have `jest` installed globally on source machine. Change it to `"scripts": { "test": "node_modules/.bin/jest" },`

Comment: Ah, this makes perfect sense. Changing this still makes it work on the source machine (Mac OS). However, I still get "'jest' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" while trying to run on cmd.exe on Win10. Running a regular 'node index.js' works just fine though. Also, if I go directly into "node_modules/.bin" and try to run 'jest' directly from there, I get the same error. This all leads me to believe it's just some annoying windows PATH problem..Any insights?

Comment: @user2402616: Since target machine is Windows, and AFAIK hidden folders on windows just has there name without dot `.`, maybe changing `.bin` to `bin` solves the problem or `"test": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\jest` or such solutions. I don't have access to Windows, otherwise it is easy to find where is the path of jest executable inside `node_modules` on a Windows machine and how to configure it inside `package.json`.

Comment: This is an interesting theory. However, changing my package.json did not resolve anything yet. Please see my new comment above, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pkg`

[Github Page](https://github.com/zeit/pkg)

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)

If you just need to run it on the second machine, `pkg` should let you package it as a standalone executable.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful, but I'm not trying to compile the app into an executable right now. I want to be able to run my tests on a different machine with full access to the source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem is either that Jest installs differently based on the OS. It may also be a problem with [import-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-local), one of the packages that Jest depends on.